# the slash (/) after a directory name on shell commands

Tags: directory, rename, filenames, slash

I have a little question here.

If I have two files, say `filea` and `fileb`, `mv filea fileb` would

- delete `fileb`
- rename `filea` to `fileb`

Then if I have two directories, say `dira` and `dirb`, `mv dira dirb` would

- move `dira` into `dirb` (it will become `dirb/dira`)

Noting that in both cases there are no notice or message, then this is pretty inconsistent to me. I think `mv dira dirb` should just overwrite `dirb` with the contents of `dira` (or merge the two directories under a directory named `dirb`).

I remember reading somewhere that a directory name with a slash (like `dira/`) is treated like a directory, and name with no slash (like `dira`) is treated like a file (to certain extents, of course). Anyway now I want to make the shell (zsh and possibly bash) respect my notation of a directory by using a slash. Is there a terminal option which enable me to enforce that?

To clarify, here is my desired behaviour:

- `mv dira dirb` results in `dirb` being overwritten with the contents of `dira`
- `mv dira dirb/` results in `dira` being moved into `dirb` (in `dirb/dira`)

Has anyone thought the same way as me? Or am I just weird?

Comment: I think your desired behavior would be rather dangerous.

Comment: @starblue: yes I agree that it is dangerous, but I'd rather live with something dangerous, than inconsistency

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a bit inconsistent, even within the GNU tools.

One problem with your proposal is that non-empty directories cannot be removed. Apart from that, `-T` (in GNU land, anyway) approximates what you want (the first case):

```
$ ls dira/ dirb/
dira/:
a

dirb/:
b
$ mv -iT dira/ dirb/
mv: overwrite `dirb/'? y
mv: cannot move `dira/' to `dirb/': Directory not empty
$ rm dirb/b 
$ mv -iT dira/ dirb/
mv: overwrite `dirb/'? y
$ ls dira/ dirb/
ls: cannot access dira/: No such file or directory
dirb/:
a
```

Comment: You could also add an alias, e.g. `alias ren=mv -T`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to move everything from dira to dirb you can run `mv dira/* dirb`.

As per mv man page on my HP-UX.

`The mv command moves:`

`+  One or more directory subtrees (directory1, [directory2, ...])
    to a new or existing directory (dest-directory).`

Comment: Your command would miss all dotfiles.

Comment: Who needs dot files anyway ;)

Comment: And if it's an issue, `shopt -s dotglob` in bash will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The following are solutions to obtain an overall more consistent behaviors (at least with the `mv` and `cp` commands).

### For the move (`mv`) command

One can get a slightly more consistent behavior by using the `-i` option:

`mv -i SOURCE DEST`

This would warn and ask confirmation when `filea` would overwrite an already existing `fileb` but would give no warning in any of the other cases, that is, one gets a warning and confirmation only when data loss is about to happen.

`$ mv -i filea fileb` :

- **if `fileb` does not already exist**, `filea` is silently renamed to `fileb`
- **if `fileb` already exist**, confirmation is requested before overwriting `fileb` with `filea`

`$ mv -i dira dirb` :

- **if `dirb` does not already exist**, `dira` is silently renamed to `dirb`
- **if `dirb` already exist**, `dira` is silently moved into `dirb`

A permanent solution is to create an alias: `$ alias mv='mv -i'`

### For the copy (`cp`) command

For the `cp` command a similar `-i` option exists. However `cp SOURCE DEST` would not behave as `mv -i SOURCE DEST` if `SOURCE` is a directory, because `cp` would omit any directory if the `-r` option is not specified.

So, to get a similar behavior as with `mv -i` one can rather use the following:

`$ cp -ir SOURCE DEST`

This would treat files and directory similarly (as the `mv -i` command would) and would warn and ask confirmation before overwriting.

`$ cp -ir filea fileb` :

- **if `fileb` does not already exist**, `filea` is silently copied to `fileb`
- **if `fileb` already exist**, confirmation is requested before overwriting `fileb` with a copy of `filea`

`$ cp -ir dira dirb` :

- **if `dirb` does not already exist**, `dira` is silently copied to `dirb`
- **if `dirb` already exist**, `dira` is silently copied into `dirb`

A permanent solution here is to create an alias: `$ alias cp='cp -ir'`