# Inconsistency in behavior of 'rm' when a mounted volume is involved?

Tags: symlink, rm, slash

If I run the following sequence of commands:

```
mkdir dir
ln -s dir link
rm -r link/
```

I get this output:

```
rm: cannot remove `link': Not a directory
```

I get the warning because I could simply have issued `rm -r link` or, better still, `rm link`. Regardless, that command did get the job done (i.e. removed the file named "**link**").

Things are a bit different when doing such a thing on a mounted volume, where "**dir**" is replaced with some like "**/media/my_movies**". In such a case, the entire volume will be wiped, not just the symlink as in the previous example.

Why is it like that? Is this some bug in `rm`, or is this expected? Why the inconsistency?

**UPDATE**: Maybe I was dizzy when I was experiencing this because when I try now, "**dir**" is not getting deleted while its contents are, and in both cases (mounted and local directory). I'm using Linux **2.6.32**, and I think I was using **2.6.37** then.

Comment: The mounted volume was an NTFS partition. I haven't tried with another filesystem, so I don't know if it has anything to with it.

Comment: [NTFS doesn't have an exact match for the unix concept of symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Microsoft_Windows). Your NTFS driver is translating between symbolic links and one of the similar concepts on NTFS, but the behavior is not exactly the same (perhaps it's using a junction point, which is closer to a hard link).

Comment: See also [the slash (/) after a directory name on shell commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/870/the-slash-after-a-directory-name-on-shell-commands/874#874). POSIX says that `foo/` is mostly equivalent to `foo/.`, but implementations aren't very conforming on this point (even OpenBSD: with your example, `rm -r link/` just removes the link).

Answer (score 3):

On my system (Debian; Linux 2.6; `rm --version` reports GNU coreutils 8.5), whether or not **dir** is a mount point, the following removes **file**, but not **dir** or **link**, and gives me the same error you saw:

```
# mkdir dir && touch dir/file && ln -s dir link
# rm -r link/
rm: cannot remove `link': Not a directory
# ls
dir  link
# ls -l dir
total 0

# mount .../scratch_filesystem dir
# touch dir/file
# rm -r link/
rm: cannot remove `link': Not a directory
# ls
dir  link
# ls -l dir
total 0
```

If I'm following you right, your `rm -r link/` command doesn't remove **file**, unless **dir/** is a mount point.  If that's the case, I think you're seeing a bug in `rm`.  There's no good reason for a mount point to change its behavior like that.

It would be interesting to know what version of `rm` you're using.

Comment: my `rm` is the same version as yours

Comment: How odd!  What happens if you do `env -i /bin/rm -r link/` instead of just `rm -r link/`?  I.e. clear the environment and avoid any potential shell aliases.

Comment: See my update question: I'm now getting what you are getting. If it happens again, I'll try the `env` thing... I wish I should have tried when I was still having the problem.