# When should I use a trailing slash on a directory?

Tags: directory, filenames, slash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How linux handles multiple path separators (/home////username///file)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

Most commands I use in linux behave exactly the same whether I include the trailing slash `/` character on the end of a directory name or not.

For example:

```
ls /home/cklein
ls /home/cklein/

cp foo bar
cp foo/ bar/
```

When does this trailing slash matter?  What is the semantic meaning of the trailing slash?

Comment: I think the answers here cover the subject okay—it doesn't seem direly in need of new answers—but @djsmith is correct; it's not a duplicate.  The other question is *related* but not at all the same.

Comment: Honestly, this isn't a duplicate at all.  This is about *trailing* slashes on a directory, not multiple consecutive slashes.  I just wrote a good test case with `rsync` that I want to post here for illustration of the different cases, but I can't until the question is reopened.

Comment: Agreed - I added my nomination to reopen.

Comment: I've reopened because https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/870/the-slash-after-a-directory-name-on-shell-commands is a better duplicate.

Comment: Since you're still around, would you mind at least not accepting a one-liner answer that didn't even get its meager facts right?

Answer (score 67):

One good example is moving a file into a directory:

```
mv some_file foo
```

vs.

```
mv some_file foo/
```

If `foo` doesn't exist, the first will rename `some_file` to `foo`, rather than the intended `foo/some_file`; the second will complain, which is what you want.

If `foo` does exists but isn't a directory, the first can clobber the `foo` file; again, the second will complain.

`cp` presents similar issues.

Working on some old versions of SunOS, I developed the habit of appending `/.`, because the system actually ignored a trailing `/` on a file name; for example, `/etc/motd/` would refer to the file rather than being an error.  Later versions of SunOS / Solaris don't seem to have that problem.

Answer (score 45):

It is *completely* dependent on the tool. `rm` won't let you remove a symlink to a directory if there's a slash at the end, and rsync does different things if the source file specification has a slash at the end.

Comment: **Pay very close attention when using `rsync`!!!** The trailing slash really matters.

Comment: For the most part, a trailing `/` means “treat this as a directory, dereference the symlink if it is one, complain if it isn't a directory”. This behavior is mandated for utilities specified by POSIX. Rsync's source argument is a notable exception.

Comment: Note that by default, `chown -R  /dir1/symlink1` will not perform recursion when the target is a symbolic link; however, `chown -R /dir1/symlink1/` will do what you would expect.

Comment: It does depend on the tool, but the `rm` case is not a good example for this: The difference here is not related to `rm`. In `rm ./symlinkToDir`, symlinkToDir is a symlink. But in `rm ./symlinkToDir/`, symlinkToDir/ is the same as symlinkToDir/. by definition, and that is the directory the symlink points to. The chown example @chrisfargen is very similar.

Comment: Even though the OP asked specific for Linux, it may be worth noting that the OS or flavor of tools used may make a difference. One notable example is `cp` which has a different behavior when using the `-r` option on OS X (BSD cp) and Linux (GNU cp).  `cp -r src/ dest` will only copy the contents of `src` into `dest` when using BSD cp but will copy the direcory `src` itself into `dest` when using GNU cp. (see http://jondavidjohn.com/linux-vs-osx-the-cp-command/)

Comment: @mathlehmann Nice find. Devs wanting to be too clever by half again. Instead of a clear-as-day additional option ("--copy-unto" for example), let's use obscure syntax that no-one ever remembers how to use.

Comment: This answer says "rsync does different things if the **remote file specification** has a slash at the end," but it appears that it's really only if the *source* file specification has a slash that you get different behavior - right?  It doesn't seem to matter whether there is or isn't a slash on the destination directory, regardless of which file (if any) is remote.  Or am I missing something?  (Also @Gilles.)

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, with rsync, a trailing `/` matters for *source* files. It doesn't matter whether the file is remote.

Answer (score 20):

`foo/` is like `foo/.`, so if `foo` is a symlink to a directory, `foo/` is a directory (not a symlink), and if `foo` is not a directory or a symlink to a directory, then you get a ENOTDIR error for anything trying to access `foo/`. That's the behavior on Linux.

Behavior may differ on other systems.

See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_13) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_75) to see what POSIX/SUS have to say about it.

Comment: I've edited the first two links to POSIX specifications but I'm not fully confident about the third link - which I presume should be to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_75

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's annoying that the TC2 update is now available at the same URL as the previous versions but with completely different HTML anchors. Many of the links are even broken there, so I'd expect it will change again. Might be better to [link to the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20110811062911/http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_59) to get consistent links.

Comment: "`foo/` is like `foo/.`" - It seems you haven't said they work exactly the same. Could you explain what might be the practical difference between them?

Answer (score 12):

In rsync, the man page reads as follows:

```
   A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid  creating
   an  additional  directory level at the destination.  You can think of a
   trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory"
   as  opposed  to  "copy  the  directory  by name", but in both cases the
   attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the  contain-
   ing  directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the follow-
   ing commands copies the files in the same way, including their  setting
   of the attributes of /dest/foo:

          rsync -av /src/foo /dest
          rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
```

The trailing slash on the *destination* doesn't matter at all.  Only on the source.  (And then, of course, it only matters if the source is a directory rather than a single file or a glob.)

To illustrate the directory to directory use case:

```
$ mkdir foo bar baz
$ chmod 700 foo
$ chmod 750 bar
$ chmod 705 baz
$ echo hello > foo/file1
$ chmod 606 foo/file1 
$ ls -n
total 0
drwxr-x---  2 501  20   68 Aug  8 15:29 bar/
drwx---r-x  2 501  20   68 Aug  8 15:29 baz/
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/
$ ls -n foo
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1
$ rsync -a foo bar
$ rsync -a foo baz/
$ rsync -a foo bif
$ rsync -a foo bonk/
$ ls -n
total 0
drwxr-x---  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 bar/
drwx---r-x  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 baz/
drwxr-xr-x  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 bif/
drwxr-xr-x  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 bonk/
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/
$ ls -n *
bar:
total 0
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/

baz:
total 0
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/

bif:
total 0
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/

bonk:
total 0
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/

foo:
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1
$ rm -rf b*
$ mkdir bar baz
$ chmod 750 bar
$ chmod 705 baz
$ rsync -a foo/ bar
$ rsync -a foo/ baz/
$ rsync -a foo/ bif
$ rsync -a foo/ bonk/
$ ls -n
total 0
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 bar/
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 baz/
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 bif/
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 bonk/
drwx------  3 501  20  102 Aug  8 15:30 foo/
$ ls -n *
bar:
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1

baz:
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1

bif:
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1

bonk:
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1

foo:
total 8
-rw----rw-  1 501  20  6 Aug  8 15:30 file1
$
```

Comment: +1.  I use `rsync` all the time and have done so for many years, and I can still never remember the exact details of rsync's handling of a trailing slash on the source dir.  I **always** have to `--dry-run` it first or read the man page.  It's good to see this answer, but it's unlikely to fix my memory :(