# Is rsync ~/foo target/foo the same as rsync ~/foo/ target/foo/?

Tags: rsync

Is rsync ~/foo target/foo the same as Is rsync ~/foo/ target/foo/?

Comment: I included full test results illustrating the answer to this question, in my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384837/135943

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The trailing slash on the source directory determines whether the directory and its contents or just its contents will be copied. And that's all that matters.

Given:

```
a/b
a/c
```

Then:

```
$ rsync a/ d/
$ ls d
b
c
```

But:

```
$ rsync a d/
$ ls d
a
```

The trailing slash on the *destination*, on the other hand, doesn't matter.

The fact that your example already has a directory in the destination with the same name as the source directory is not really important...`target/foo` is always destination. In the examples above just replace `a` with `~/foo` and `d` with `target/foo` and it works the same...

```
$ rsync ~/foo/ target/foo/
$ ls target/foo
b
c
```

...and...

```
$ rsync ~/foo target/foo
$ ls target/foo
foo
```

Comment: That explains some of my dupes - Thanks :)

Comment: You bet! Cheers.