# Why does `rm` claim my symlink is a directory?

Tags: directory, symlink, rm

I made a symlink to a directory like this:

```
ln -s /some/directory symlink
```

Now I'd like to remove the symlink:

```
rm symlink/
```

This doesn't work. The error message is:

> ```
> rm: cannot remove 'symlink/': Is a directory
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Why does `rm` claim my symlink is a directory? How to remove the symlink properly?

Comment: It's not that I haven't searched for possible duplicates. See [this meta answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4444/108618). So disappointed by "search"…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this question: [*When should I use a trailing slash on a directory?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50499/108618) and [one of the answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50503/108618) says:

> `rm` won't let you remove a symlink to a directory if there's a slash at the end

It's like you told `rm` the object is a directory.

```
rm symlink/   # wrong
rm symlink    # right
```